# need help with formatting a USB Drive as exFat

Tags: partitioning, usb, exfat

I'm trying to do this tutorial I found https://linuxopsys.com/topics/how-to-format-usb-drive-as-exfat-on-linux

when I get to the "sudo fdisk /dev/sdb" step, it says :

This disk is currently in use - repartitioning is probably a bad idea. It's recommended to unmount all file systems, and swapoff all swap partitions on this disk.

Please help with how to proceed! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the USB got automounted.  From the Files app, look for any sdb1 (or whatever letter the USB gets) devices and click on the uparrow to unmount.
Or from a terminal, (ctrl+alt+t to start one), type

```
df
```

and see if any sdb partitions are mounted (usually under /media/username/xxxxxxx). unmount them

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Then try your fdisk command.